# How do I write a multi-line text in pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to convert one long text to multiline text. I wrote some code, and it mostly works. But I have some problems in line width calculation. Because the lines getting shorter and shorter. Probably caused by `lastCalculatedWidth` or `resultTextLength` or both of them. I tried a lot of things but I'm very confused and I want to solve this as soon as possible, I would appreciate it if you could help me.[image: output-image]

```py
text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec augue leo, pulvinar maaaıs sagittis sit amet, tristique viverra mauris. Sed mauris quam, faucibus id pretium non, varius eget leo."
result_text = ""
messageBreakLineIndexes = []
calculatedWords = 0
messageLineWidth = draw.textlength(text, font=font)
resultTextLength = 0
lastCalculatedWidth = 0
calculationSwitch = True

while calculatedWords < len(text.split()):
    result_text += text.split()[calculatedWords] + " "
    resultTextLength += draw.textlength(text.split()[calculatedWords], font=font)
    if resultTextLength > img.width - 60:
        result_text = result_text.rstrip()
        result_text = result_text.rsplit(" ", 1)[0]

        messageBreakLineIndexes.append(len(result_text))
        calculatedWords -= 1
        
        resultTextLength -= draw.textlength(result_text.rstrip(), font=font) - lastCalculatedWidth
        lastCalculatedWidth = draw.textlength(result_text.rstrip(), font=font)
    calculatedWords += 1

print(messageBreakLineIndexes)
for i in range(len(messageBreakLineIndexes)):
    index = messageBreakLineIndexes[i]
    result_text = result_text[:index+i] + "\n" + result_text[index+i:]
draw.text(text_position, result_text, font=font, fill=text_color)
```

Comment: you deleted question about `TinyDB` but I had information. For your example you have to use `t = db.table('my_table')` and `t.all()` instead of `db.all()`. Or you have to change your JSON from `{"my_table": ..` into `{"_default": ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i merged codes with mine and @Attersson's answer because `draw.textlength` cannot work with `\n`. It's look like fine now.[image]

```py
text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec augue leo, pulvinar maaaıs sagittis sit amet, tristique viverra mauris. Sed mauris quam, faucibus id pretium non, varius eget leo."
result_text = ""
messageBreakLineIndexes = []
resultTextLength = 0

words = text.split()

# Iterate over the words directly as an iterable, not by len
for word in words:
    # Check the width of the current line plus the next word
    word_width = draw.textlength(word, font=font)
    if resultTextLength + word_width <= img.width - 60:
        # If the line isn't too wide, add the word to the line
        result_text += word + " "
        resultTextLength += word_width + draw.textlength(" ", font=font)  # Add space width
    else:
        # If the line is too wide, break the line
        result_text = result_text.rstrip()
        messageBreakLineIndexes.append(len(result_text))
        result_text += word + " "
        resultTextLength = word_width + draw.textlength(" ", font=font)  # Reset line width

for i in range(len(messageBreakLineIndexes)):
    index = messageBreakLineIndexes[i]
    result_text = result_text[:index+i] + "\n" + result_text[index+i:]
draw.text(text_position, result_text, font=font, fill=text_color)
```

Answer (score 2):

`resultTextLength` doesn't get correctly reset after a line break and `lastCalculatedWidth` doesn't accurately keep track of the width of the last word that fits on the line before a break, which triggers cumulative errors in calculating the line width as the loop iterates. So the lines get progressively shorter.

Try something like this:

```
text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec augue leo, pulvinar maaaıs sagittis sit amet, tristique viverra mauris. Sed mauris quam, faucibus id pretium non, varius eget leo."

# Split the text by spaces to get words
words = text.split()

result_text = ""
messageBreakLineIndexes = []
resultTextLength = 0
img_width = 800

# Iterate over the words directly as an iterable, not by len
for word in words:
    # Check the width of the current line plus the next word
    word_width = draw.textlength(word, font=font)
    if resultTextLength + word_width <= img_width - 60:
        # If the line isn't too wide, add the word to the line
        result_text += word + " "
        resultTextLength += word_width + draw.textlength(" ", font=font)  # Add space width
    else:
        # If the line is too wide, break the line
        result_text = result_text.rstrip() + "\n"
        messageBreakLineIndexes.append(len(result_text))
        result_text += word + " "
        resultTextLength = word_width + draw.textlength(" ", font=font)  # Reset line width

draw.text(text_position, result_text, font=font, fill=text_color)
```

Let me know if it works.
Note my line with the comment `# Reset line width`

Comment: I answered the question. your codes works fine but there were some missing codes. Thanks for your help. I appreciate it.